# Can't call function from class by std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector, stdthread

I'm trying to make a class `Threads` to call for example 20 classes called `Thread` that will perform an action. `Thread` contains only function, this funtion is `Compress` and informations about the thread(if its busy etc.). I also have to add that `Threads` keeps `Thread` classes in `std::vector` called `threads`. Yeah i should have picked better names. haha

Whole program seems to work well, but when i use `std::thread` in `Threads` file to call `Compress` function from `Thread` class then I run into programs when i'm trying to compile this.

so first i will show code, but only parts that will be helpful, I think content of `Thread.cpp` will be useless, but I will post it here if you it will be needed

```cpp
//Thread.h:

class Thread
{
public:
    BOOL isBusy = FALSE;

    Threads *threadParent;

    Thread();

    ~Thread();

    BOOL Compress() { return prvCompress(); }

private:
    BOOL prvCompress();
};
```

```cpp
//Threads.h

class Threads
{
public:
    std::vector<Thread>threads;

    File *myFile;

    Threads(File *myFile_);

    ~Threads();

    BOOL CallCompress() { return prvCallCompress(); }

private:

    BOOL prvCallCompress();
};
```

Here from `Threads.cpp` i will just paste this calling function

```cpp
//Threads.cpp

BOOL Threads::prvCallCompress()
{
    //for (UIN8 i = 0; i < ThreadsNumber; i++)
    //  std::thread(threads[i].Compress()).detach();


    std::thread(this->threads.at(0).Compress()).detach();

    return FALSE;
}
```

Errors:

```
Error number 1:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)'    FileSlapper ...\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\thread   51  

Error number 2:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2672   'invoke': no matching overloaded function found FileSlapper ...\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\thread   55
```

What have I tried:

So basically I tried doing this without std::thread and it works well.

I also tried to use this instead of calling that function:

```cpp
    std::thread([&] { std::cout << threads[0].wasntUsed << std::endl; }).detach();
```

and this returned `FALSE` as it should, no errors

I also tried to just make a `std::thread` without even calling it, but it also ends up with an error:

```cpp
    std::thread(this->threads.at(0).Compress());
```

if i forgot to add something I will definitely do it if you guys ask. But i'm sure here I posted everything that its needed.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately this was closed before I could post my answer; if you look at how you are spawning your thread, you are effectively doing this: `auto result = this->threads.at(0).Compress(); std::thread(result);`. However, `std::thread` needs a function to run, so instead you should provide it that expression as a function, e.g. `std::thread([&] { this->threads.at(0).Compress(); });`

Comment: You need to pass a callable object (a function-pointer, lambda, functor object, etc.) to the thread constructor. In your code you  *call* the `Compress` function, which returns a `BOOL` value which I assume is an integer type, and as such it's not callable.

Comment: You need to pass a function pointer as first parameter of the `std::thread` constructor and a reference wrapper or pointer for the object to call the function for as a second parameter, if it's a member function pointer, followed by any function parameters: `std::thread(&Thread::Compress, std::ref(this->threads.at(0)))....` Note that you need to make sure the address of the `Thread` remains stable while the thread is running; adding elements to the `threads` vector could violate this requirement resuling in UB.

Comment: Simple solution: Use a lambda that calls the `Compress` function: `std::thread([&]() { threads.at(0).Compress(); }).detach();`